# Winternitz Parameter in WOTS+ and XMSS

Tags: signature, hash-tree

What is the parameter for? I read that in XMSS it is a member of the set {4, 16}, but what does it exactly mean? I also read that the bigger the $w$ parameter, the shorter the signatures but the `keygen`, `sign` and `vrfy` become slower. How do I pick an optimal $w$ parameter? Is it the height of the Merkle tree?

Answer (score 1):

[This paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/191.pdf) answers your question most succinctly:

> The size of a Winternitz signature is roughly $mn/w$ bits and signing roughly requires $2^wm/w$
> hash operations, where $m$ is the bit length of the hash value to be signed, $n$ is the output length of
> the hash function used in the scheme, and $w$ is the Winternitz parameter determining the tradeoff between signature size and signature generation time.

The reference paper [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8391) goes into detail on how the parameter $w$ is used in various algorithms.  Per the paper:

> The parameter $w$ can be chosen from the set {4, 16}.
> A larger value of $w$ results in shorter signatures but slower overall
> signing operations; it has little effect on security.  Choices of $w$
> are limited to the values 4 and 16 since these values yield optimal
> trade-offs and easy implementation.

An example of the parameter being used is in Algorithm 5: WOTS_sign - Generating a signature from a private key and a message.

Section 2.2 of [this paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/965.pdf) goes into further detail about time-memory tradeoff.

Additionally section 4 goes into further depth with performance comparisons of different parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The height of the merkle tree is an independent parameter. The Winternitz parameter — $w$ — comes up because to sign or verify a WOTS+ signature the first step is to encode your message as a list of integers from $0$ to $w - 1$ (inclusive). For example the string `"hello"` is encoded in ascii as `01101000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111`. If $w$ were $16$ then each integer would correspond to $4$ bits of the message. Like this:

```
0110 1000 0110 0101 0110 1100 0110 1100 0110 1111
   6    8    6    5    6   12    6   12    6   15
```

If $w$ were $4$ then each integer would correspond to $2$ bits and the sequence would be like that:

```
01 10 10 00 01 10 01 01 01 10 11 00 01 10 11 00 01 10 11 11
 1  2  2  0  1  2  1  1  1  2  3  0  1  2  3  0  1  2  3  3
```

So $4$ and $16$ are just values that make conversion simple and efficient. A big $w$ makes for a small sequence of big numbers, a small $w$ makes a big sequence of small numbers. Bigger sequences tend to result in bigger signatures. Bigger numbers increase the amount of hashes you need to calculate.

If your hashes have $n$ bytes and you're signing a message of $m$ bytes then the length of your signature will be

$$n\cdot\left(\left\lceil \frac{8\cdot m}{\log_2(w)} \right\rceil + \left\lfloor \frac{\log_2\left(\left\lceil \frac{8\cdot m}{\log_2(w)} \right\rceil \cdot (w - 1)\right)}{\log_2(w)} \right\rfloor + 1 \right)$$

bytes. So you could try plugging some values of $w$ to see which ones give you a reasonable size.